# Is there a proxy manager app for iOS that can bypass some URLs and connect to them directly?

Tags: iphone, proxy

Is there a proxy manager app for iOS that can bypass some URLs and connect to them directly (by specifying rules)?

If not, do you know of a solution that this can be done, even if it needs creating a custom app?

Mac has this feature, but iPhone doesn't have this option.

Comment: I don't understand your question - if you don't have a proxy you always directly connect to the URL

Comment: A proxy that proxies some traffic but allows others to bypass is an intelligent or selective proxy. I’ve only see these at the network head end (close to the router). This isn’t an app

Comment: bro who downvoted and even closed the question. It's pretty clear. A proxy manager that has a possibility letting direct connection for some URLs (rule-based). Mac Natively has this option, but I didn't find it for iPhone. BTW, I've found an app that does this.

Comment: Shopping questions are considered off topic here per the [Help]

Answer (score 0):

I've found two apps.

1 - FoXray, which does the job, but with some limitations. (seems to be buggy in some circumstances) apps.apple.com/us/app/foxray-premium/id6448898396

2 - Brook, which does this in a pretty advanced way, but it's a premium feature.